# How to convert "07-JUL-22 08.54.22.153000000 AM" to datetime object in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert "07-JUL-22 08.54.22.153000000 AM" to a datetime object in python in order to be able to perform timedelta operations inside a pandas dataframe!

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime. Also, you should try before just asking. Post the code that you are trying with and ask a SEPCIFIC question.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm so sorry, it was my first question on StackOverflow, I'll improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_datetime` can infer `07-JUL-22 08:54:22.153000000 AM`, you can do

```py
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['date'].str.replace(r'(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})', r'\1:\2:\3', regex=True)
)
```

```
print(df)

                              date                   date2
0  07-JUL-22 08:54:22.153000000 AM 2022-07-07 08:54:22.153
```

Answer (score 0):

Nanoseconds are a bit of a problem for the batteries included with Python:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = "07-jul-22 08.54.22.153000 am"
dt = datetime.strptime(d, "%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p")
```

Note that the timestamp is truncated to microseconds. How important are those for your application?

You can truncate nanoseconds to microseconds with a regex:

```
import re
d = "07-jul-22 08.54.22.153000000 am"
d = re.sub(r"(\d\d\d\d\d\d)\d\d\d", r"\1", d)
```

(Cheat sheet: https://strftime.org/ )